# Can I use "contortion" to express conflict or a fight? In what ways can I use it?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms

I have seen many examples of the word [contortion](https://www.lexico.com/definition/contortion). There is the twisting of the body in which you make a contortion. But can it be used as a synonym for a fight? For example:

> *Humans start unnecessary contortions amongst each other.*

Is that sentence correct?
Please explain all the definitions of this word and how I can use this in different sentences.

Comment: Perhaps ["between each other"](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/between_each_other/synonyms) is more idiomatic.

Comment: I think  the word [**wrestle**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/wrestle) would be a better fit.

Comment: If you are going to use *contortions* to describe a fight, it should be *contortions* ***against***, not *amongst*. Using *amongst* in this construction could describe a yoga class.

Comment: A contortion as a fight or conflict among people is an incorrect use of the term. You should look this up in dictionaries to get examples of how to use this word.

Comment: You seem to already know what the word means. In view of what you know about its meaning, why do you think that it could be used this way? Without such an explanation, there doesn't seem to be a real question here; as it stands now it can be answered with a simple 'no'.

Answer (score -1):

> can it be used as a synonym for a fight?

Yes, because any word can be used in any way with whatever intended meaning one wants. This is how language evolves.

Many people, if not all, will consider it to be a *wrong* usage, however. The word **contortion** *does not* have the acceptation of 'a fight'. As a consequence, at least some of your audience is bound to be confused when coming across this particular turn of phrase.